# TypeError : module is not a function - Browserify & Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, browserify

I'm trying for the first time to test my angular bundle create with browserify,
but when I run Karma, i have this error :

```
Chrome 50.0.2661 (Windows 10 0.0.0) it checks dataService objects, encountered a declaration exception FAILED
    TypeError: module is not a function
        at Suite.<anonymous> (C:/Users//1832d4dc6c0fa77886e1cae0916aaa85.browserify:811:13 <- testDrawer/testDataService.js:7:0)
        at Object.require.C:\Users\\angularjs\testDrawer\testDataService.js (C:/Users//Temp/1832d4dc6c0fa77886e1cae0916aaa85.browserify:805:1 <- testDrawer/testDataService.js:1:0)
        at s (C:/Users//AppData/Local/Temp/1832d4dc6c0fa77886e1cae0916aaa85.browserify:1:262 <- node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:0)
        at C:/Users//angularjs/testDrawer/testDataService.js:1:34
Chrome 50.0.2661 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 2 (1 FAILED) (skipped 1)      ERROR (0.026 secs / 0.003 secs)
```

Error comes from :

```
describe("it checks dataService objects,", function() {

it('it verifies installations');

var dataService;

beforeEach(module('drawerApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_dataService_) {
    dataService = _dataService_;
}));

it('it verifies tool', function(){
    expect(dataService.color.equals('black'));
});
});
```

My karma config :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'drawer/*.js',
        'drawer/**/*.js',
        'testDrawer/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: ['karma.conf.js' , 'drawer/drawerBundle.js' ],

    browserify: {
        debug: true
    },


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        'drawer/*.js' : ['browserify'],
        'drawer/**/*.js': ['browserify'],
        'testDrawer/*.js': ['browserify']
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
})
`enter code here`};
```

The first test success but the second one failed beacause of :

```
 beforeEach(module('drawerApp'));
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the exact error? Probably some node_module is missing and needs to be installed.

Comment: I only test javascript files, i didn't know you have to include librairies in html file, thank you, i will try it.

Comment: It doesn't work. Nothing changes

Comment: You might be having an index.html file where you declare `ng-app` along with the declaration of all the script files in it. You need to add a script reference for `angular-mocks.js` to that file.

Comment: It's not coming from the html file, angular app works alone.